unable to take input of strings from user
I have to make an array of structure for cricketers presenting their name, age etc. and take input of each value from user . I am trying to get value of name from the user but my code editor keeps on skipping that line i have tried gets , scanf with %s , scanf with %[^\n]s and fgets nothing works the whole line gets skipped . I want to take full name as input.
"none of them works fgets ,scanf , gets nonw of them works the line skipps itself tried alot of solutions none of them works "
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define name_len 20

int main (){
    printf("enter no of players : ");
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    typedef struct cricketers {
        char name[name_len];
        int age;
        int testMatches;
        float avgRuns;
    } players;
    players arr[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("enter name of the player indexed %d",i);
        fgets(arr[i].name,name_len,stdin);
        printf("enter age of the player indexed %d",i);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i].age);
        printf("enter no of test matches played by the player indexed %d",i);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i].testMatches);
        printf("enter avg runs in each test math of the player indexed %d",i);
        scanf("%f",&arr[i].avgRuns);
    }
    

    return 0;
}

pliz help 
i already tried this and that fgets func too
gets(arr[i].name);
scanf("%s",arr[i].name);
scanf("%[^\n]s",arr[i].name);
scanf("%[^\n]",arr[i].name);


fgets() leaves the newline in the buffer. So arr[i].name will end with a newline. You should remove this. Other than that, your code looks fine to me.

scanf(" %[^\n]", arr[i].name);
